# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: sqlite_schema

Tags: python, sqlite

I am facing a weird issue. In TablePlus when I run the following command it returns table but same query does not work in Python.

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    sqlite_schema
WHERE 
    type ='table' 
    AND 
    name NOT LIKE 'lookup%';
```

Python code is given below:

```
def get_connection():
    path = 'data.sqlite3'
    connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
    return connection

sql_select = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_schema WHERE type ='table' AND name NOT LIKE 'lookup%';"
cursor = connection.execute(sql_select)
```

Error:

```
cursor = connection.execute(sql_select)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: sqlite_schema
```

I am using SQLite 3.36

Comment: https://sqlite.org/schematab.html - look at paragraph 2 for alternative names

Comment: @balderman so `sqlite_master` worked. But why `sqlite_schema` worked for the same db in TablePlus but not in Python?

Comment: I have no idea.. :-)

Comment: You may be using version 3.36 in TablePlus, but the Python version is older than that. What does `select sqlite_version();` return in Python?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield 3.29.0

Comment: The name change took effect in version 3.33.0

Answer (score 7):

Change sqlite_schema for sqlite_master in PHP CPANEL VERSION 92, SUCCESS